# Fail to name a child node in binary tree layout

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw a customed binary tree. I read through the manual. As my understanding, a children node could be named. However, the following code is unexpected. Two circles are drawn on the same node. How to fix my codes? Thanks very much!

```
% !TEX program = lualatex

\documentclass[12pt,A4]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {graphs,graphdrawing} 
\usegdlibrary {trees, layered}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture} [binary tree layout, ] 
    \node[name=nodeA]{A}
    child { 
        node[ fill=green, name=nodeB]{B}
        child [missing]
        child { node {C}
            child { node {D} } 
            child [missing]
        }
    };
    \draw [red] (nodeA) circle [radius=3mm];
    \draw [green] (nodeB) circle [radius=8mm]; 
\end{tikzpictur}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

Your problem can be simple solved by use of pure `tikz`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary {trees, layered}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) {A}
    child {node (B) [fill=green] {B}
        child [missing]
        child { node {C}
            child { node {D} }
            child [missing]
                }
            }
    child [missing]
;
\draw [red] (A) circle [radius=3mm];
\draw [green] (B) circle [radius=8mm];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:** It is not clear what is your problem. From your answer, which is actually new question, follows, that you sometime have many nodes in some tree level. That in such a case they will not overlap, you need to define `sibling distance` with appropriate size. For example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary {trees, layered}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
sibling distance = 22mm
                        ]
\node (A) {A}
    child {node (B) [fill=green] {B}
        child [missing]
        child { node {C}
            child { node {D} }
            child [missing]
                }
            }
    child {node {something}}
;
\draw [red] (A) circle [radius=3mm];
\draw [green] (B) circle [radius=8mm];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

but in this case if like to draw circles over this new node than can happen, that circles will overlap nodes in a neighborhoods. Meaning that your way to emphasize some nodes with circles in not promising way.

Since the context of your question is unknown, is hard to help you. For drawing trees seem to be in your cases use of the `forest` package a better choice.

Comment: Thank you! The code works perfectly. However, another question emerges: how can I hidden the edges? I use the "every edge/.style={}". It does not work.

Comment: I find the correct setting, "edge from parent/.style={}" should be used instead of "every edge/.style={}"

Comment: Where in above diagram you not need edge? Correct syntax is `edge from parent[draw=none]`

Comment: @Forrest, if my answer solve (perfectly, as you say) your problem, you may consider to accept it (by clicking on check mark at top left side of answer) .

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: I checked your answer. However, I found there is a flaw. Since you disable the option“binary tree layout”. Some times, the nodes would be overlapped, especially, when I change the size of node. So, I wonder it is possible: name a child in the option“binary tree layout”

Comment: @Forrest, Now is not clear, what is your problem. Find a general solution? You may check `forest` package ...